# Inserting latex text in an image using gimp

Tags: gimp, latex

I want to insert a latex text in an image I created with GIMP.

Is it possible using GIMP? If not, is there any other way to do this?
Can I use geogebra or something similar?

Comment: If you're already using LaTex, then you should consider [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: I've heard that that is much more complicated, but I am using latex

Answer (score 2):

Gimp can import PDF or EPS, two formats you can easily get from a Latex file. You have to set the correct PPI on import to achieve the size in pixels you need in Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [GeoGebra](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geogebra) can be an option. Use the *Text* tool (the second tool from the second toolset from right in version 5, or the first tool from the second toolset in version 4), click somewhere in the *Graphics View* and type your LaTeX input in the popup window (you may need to enable the checkbox *LaTeX formula*). Then, you can copy the *Graphics View to Clipboard* in the *Edit* menu, or use the *File* menu and option *Export* to save the content of the *Graphics View* in a PNG file, for example.